# Quantum Psuedo Telepathy vs. "Deterministic random seed" (piece of paper)

Tags: quantum-information, foundations

I'm trying to get a better understanding of "quantum psuedo telepathy."  It seems as though all games that can be won with entanglement simply exploit coordination.

In any of these games, what stops me from pre-determining a random seed and just playing the game with that seed?

Is there really nothing special about this other than a joint-correlation? (which could be done by just writing down numbers on a piece of paper in advance.)

Comment: Isn't this just the same as for Bell inequalities: You *cannot* violate Bell inequalities with a pre-determined random seed?  (Unless, of course, the person you play against also has a pre-determined random seed, that is, you know *beforehand* which questions can be asked.)